# Join tables where columns have spaces in them

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't seem to get this one working. I have two tables I want to join but one of the columns has a space in a few of the titles. I am trying the following code with out success.

I have not bought in the columns from the join yet because I want to test that I can make the join.

```
SELECT rcm.activitydatetime, rcm.'lead id', rcm.'new stage'
FROM customername_leads_by_lifecycle_stage_rcm AS rcm
INNER JOIN customername_leads AS leads
ON rcm.'lead id' = leads.ID;
```

The warning I get is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''lead id', rcm.'new stage' FROM customername_leads_by_lifecycle_stage_rcm AS rcm INNE' at line 1
```

Any help is always appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to use backticks instead of single quotes.  I vote to close such questions as a typographical error.

Answer (score 10):

Use backticks (`) rather than single quotes (') for column names

```
SELECT rcm.activitydatetime, rcm.`lead id`, rcm.`new stage`
FROM customername_leads_by_lifecycle_stage_rcm AS rcm
INNER JOIN customername_leads AS leads
ON rcm.`lead id` = leads.ID;
```

You may also consider renaming the columns so they don't have spaces.